# Creating a SSRS report and having issues with structure

Tags: reporting-services

I am trying to create a report for some calibrated tools from our ERP System. 
I am fairly new to SSRS and not sure how to structure it.

We would like to have 6 columns:

`PART_ID, Description, Calibration_Required, Calibrated_Date, Next_Calibration, Employee`

This Information is located in 4 Columns in the Table and are Defined by Field ID:

```
Part_ID
Description
Date_Val
String_Val

Field_ID
00004 = Calibrated Date From Date_Val
00005 = Next Calibration From Date_Val
00006 = Employee From String_Val
00007 = Calibration Required From String_Val
```

I would like to have each row in its own column and to only have the part listed once instead of 4 Times for each Field_ID.

Comment: would help if you mock up your report to show us what you want it to look like and your actual dataset results.

Comment: If you just need to display your query results, you would add a dataset with your query, add a table to the report, set the table's dataset to the one you just created, then add the fields to the table. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/create-a-basic-table-report-ssrs-tutorial?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: If the `Field_ID` is not part of your table, why is every `Part_ID` listed 4 fimes? Is your table located in some kind of database and if so, what kind? Can it be querried using a query language like SQL?

Comment: Our Data is stored SQL 2016 and the table have been created by the ERP system.

Comment: Hi All, I was able to get this completed by using a matrix Table and creating 4 User_Def_Groups and filtering them out per column. I do have another issue now though. I need to find the number of days between 2 dates in the same column defined by the User_Def_Field. I attempted to right an expression like this =Datediff("d", IIF(Fields!USER_DEF_FIELDS_ID.Value = 00004,Fields!DATE_VAL.Value, Nothing), IIF(Fields!USER_DEF_FIELDS_ID.Value = 00005,Fields!DATE_VAL.Value, Nothing)) but it did not work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I used a [common table expression CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to [pivot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017) the recordset. To mock up the data I used [mockaroo](https://mockaroo.com/).

#### Results

[image: screenshot]

#### Example Records

[image: screenshot]

#### Example SQL

```
WITH
field_descriptions
AS
(
    SELECT tbl.* FROM (VALUES
      ( '00004', 'Calibrated Date')
    , ( '00005', 'Next Calibration')
    , ( '00006', 'Employee')
    , ( '00007', 'Calibration Required')
    ) tbl ([Field_ID], [Field_Description]) 
)
,
part_data
AS
(
    SELECT tbl.* FROM (VALUES
      ( 10001, '00004', 'NSX', '26-Jan-2019', NULL)
    , ( 10001, '00005', 'NSX', '23-Aug-2018', NULL)
    , ( 10001, '00006', 'NSX', NULL, 'aludlom1')
    , ( 10001, '00007', 'NSX', NULL, 'tweek0')
    , ( 10002, '00004', 'S2000', '19-Aug-2018', NULL)
    , ( 10002, '00005', 'S2000', '31-Aug-2018', NULL)
    , ( 10002, '00006', 'S2000', NULL, 'mmiskelly7')
    , ( 10002, '00007', 'S2000', NULL, 'btwitty2')
    , ( 10003, '00004', 'LHS', '15-Jun-2018', NULL)
    , ( 10003, '00005', 'LHS', '16-Sep-2018', NULL)
    , ( 10003, '00006', 'LHS', NULL, 'ceronief')
    , ( 10003, '00007', 'LHS', NULL, 'rmccaughran5')
    , ( 10004, '00004', 'Corvette', '07-Jul-2018', NULL)
    , ( 10004, '00005', 'Corvette', '24-Oct-2018', NULL)
    , ( 10004, '00006', 'Corvette', NULL, 'jgodonh')
    , ( 10004, '00007', 'Corvette', NULL, 'rbrayley8')
    , ( 10005, '00004', 'Savana', '14-Oct-2018', NULL)
    , ( 10005, '00005', 'Savana', '08-Feb-2018', NULL)
    , ( 10005, '00006', 'Savana', NULL, 'dwilsoni')
    , ( 10005, '00007', 'Savana', NULL, 'sdunnan9')
    , ( 10006, '00004', 'Z4 M', '01-Jan-2019', NULL)
    , ( 10006, '00005', 'Z4 M', '07-Dec-2018', NULL)
    , ( 10006, '00006', 'Z4 M', NULL, 'ncopestickt')
    , ( 10006, '00007', 'Z4 M', NULL, 'tskahilla')
    , ( 10007, '00004', 'M-Class', '11-Aug-2018', NULL)
    , ( 10007, '00005', 'M-Class', '02-May-2018', NULL)
    , ( 10007, '00006', 'M-Class', NULL, 'bbamlingx')
    , ( 10007, '00007', 'M-Class', NULL, 'ddunkb')
    , ( 10008, '00004', 'Neon', '31-Oct-2018', NULL)
    , ( 10008, '00005', 'Neon', '16-Jul-2018', NULL)
    , ( 10008, '00006', 'Neon', NULL, 'vtocknell11')
    , ( 10008, '00007', 'Neon', NULL, 'thagstonk')
    , ( 10009, '00004', 'Celica', '05-Sep-2018', NULL)
    , ( 10009, '00005', 'Celica', '16-Mar-2018', NULL)
    , ( 10009, '00006', 'Celica', NULL, 'fwudeland1a')
    , ( 10009, '00007', 'Celica', NULL, 'wjennionsp')
    , ( 10010, '00004', 'Savana', '09-Oct-2018', NULL)
    , ( 10010, '00005', 'Savana', '05-Jul-2018', NULL)
    , ( 10010, '00006', 'Savana', NULL, 'dtrevena1c')
    , ( 10010, '00007', 'Savana', NULL, 'dcaseror')
    ) tbl ([Part_ID], [Field_ID], [Description], [Date_Val], [String_Val]) 
)
, 
part_data_udf
AS
(
    SELECT 
          pd.[Part_ID]
        , pd.[Field_ID]
        , fd.[Field_Description]
        , pd.[Description]
        , pd.[Date_Val]
        , pd.[String_Val]
        , [udf_field] = COALESCE(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), pd.[Date_Val], 113), ' ', '-'), pd.[String_Val])
    FROM 
        part_data AS pd
        INNER JOIN field_descriptions AS fd ON pd.[Field_ID] = fd.[Field_ID]
)
SELECT 
      [Part_ID]
    , [Description]
    , [Calibrated Date] 
    , [Next Calibration]
    , [Employee] 
    , [Calibration Required] 
FROM 
    (
    SELECT 
          pd.[Part_ID]
        , pd.[Field_Description]
        , pd.[Description]
        , pd.[udf_field] 
    FROM 
        part_data_udf pd
    ) pL
PIVOT
(
MAX([udf_field]) 
FOR [Field_Description] 
IN 
    (
      [Calibrated Date] 
    , [Next Calibration]
    , [Employee] 
    , [Calibration Required] 
    )
) AS pvt
ORDER BY [Part_ID]
```

Comment: My Table basically looks exactly like your example and your results are what im looking for.  Unfortunately most of this went over my head. Are you able to show me what this would like using a and exiting table called USER_DEF_Fields with out creating a new table ?

Comment: Can you post the table definition in your question?